# How to create a django model field mixin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a generic mixin for model fields (as opposed to form fields), the init for the mixin takes named arguments. I am running into trouble instantiating the mixin with another class.

Here is the code

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, new_arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.__class__, new_arg


class MyMixinCharField(MyMixin, models.CharField):
    pass

...

class MyMixinModelTest(models.Model):
    myfield = MyMixinCharField(max_length=512,new_arg="myarg")
```

Making the migration for this model produces the following output:

```
<class 'myapp.mixintest.fields.MyMixinCharField'> myarg 
<class 'myapp.mixintest.fields.MyMixinCharField'> None 
<class 'myapp.mixintest.fields.MyMixinCharField'> None 
Migrations for 'mixintest':   
   0001_initial.py:
        - Create model MyMixinModelTest
```

First, why is init running 3 times?  Where does the kwarg 'new_arg' in the second two?
How do I create a field mixin for django?

EDIT:
As opposed to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014282), this question asks about *field* mixins, the linked question refers to *model* mixins.

Comment: Which version of django are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.9

Comment: @solarissmoke it's not the same question.

Comment: Not even a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, why is init running 3 times?

Although the `models.py` is only imported once, the `Field` objects created therein, such as...

```
myfield = MyMixinCharField(max_length=512, new_arg="myarg")
```

...are cloned several times, which involves calling the field constructor using the keyword args they were originally created with. You can use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module to see where it's happening...

```
import traceback

class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, new_arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.__class__, new_arg
        traceback.print_stack()
```

...which shows the following several times in the output...

```
  File "django/db/migrations/state.py", line 393, in from_model
    fields.append((name, field.clone()))
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 464, in clone
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "myproj/myapp/models.py", line 11, in __init__
    traceback.print_stack()
```

---

> Where is the kwarg 'new_arg' in the second two?

When you originally called...

```
myfield = MyMixinCharField(max_length=512, new_arg="myarg")
```

...`"myarg"` is being passed in as the `new_arg` parameter to...

```
def __init__(self, new_arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

...but because you don't pass that parameter to the underlying `Field` constructor...

```
super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

...it's not stored anywhere in the underlying `Field` object, so when the field is cloned, the `new_arg` parameter isn't passed to the constructor.

However, passing that option to the superclass constructor won't work, because the `CharField` doesn't support that keyword arg, so you'll get...

```
  File "myproj/myapp/models.py", line 29, in MyMixinModelTest
    myfield = MyMixinCharField(max_length=512, new_arg="myarg")
  File "myproj/myapp/models.py", line 25, in __init__
    super(MyMixinCharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new_arg'
```

---

> How do I create a field mixin for django?

Because of this cloning behavior, if you want to add custom field options, you have to define a custom [`deconstruct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction) method so that Django can serialize your new option...

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, new_arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.new_arg = new_arg
        print self.__class__, new_arg

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(MyMixin, self).deconstruct()
        kwargs['new_arg'] = self.new_arg
        return name, path, args, kwargs


class MyMixinCharField(MyMixin, models.CharField):
    pass


class MyMixinModelTest(models.Model):
    myfield = MyMixinCharField(max_length=512, new_arg="myarg")
```

...which outputs...

```
<class 'myapp.models.MyMixinCharField'> myarg
<class 'myapp.models.MyMixinCharField'> myarg
<class 'myapp.models.MyMixinCharField'> myarg
```

Comment: I didn't answer all of my questions in my answer, you did. So I will accept yours.

Comment: Quick question, in my answer I have MyMixin inherit from models.Field, Does this affect anything?

Comment: @jmerkow It's not a particularly quick question to answer definitively, due to the use of metaclasses in `Model`. If `MyMixin` subclasses `Field` directly, then in some circumstances, functions in `CharField` which override those defined in `Field` may be ignored, and it'll end up calling the wrong function. It's probably safer to avoid that possibility, and just have the `MyMixin` subclass `object`, which is what mixins should do anyway.

Comment: That answers my question.  Do you know of any good docs on this subject?

Comment: @jmerkow Well, a quick search yields [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/533631/172176), which has a couple of links in the comments that might be of interest. Mixins are ultimately just a special case of "multiple inheritence", so you could try googling for that to see some of the pros and cons. See also: [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out after lots of tinkering and re-reading the [django docs on custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/)
You need a deconstructor along with your init. Django fields need a `deconstruct` method to serialize.

The mixin should have this method as well:

```
class MyMixin(object):
def __init__(self, new_arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.new_arg = new_arg
    super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def deconstruct(self):
    name, path, args, kwargs = super(MyMixin, self).deconstruct()
    if self.new_arg is not None:
        kwargs['new_arg'] = self.new_arg
    return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Comment: I was almost done writing a more detailed answer when you posted this. :)